# Functoriality in the group $G$ of the domain of the Baum-Connes map

Tags: gr.group-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Lück claims in his preliminary book, that the left hand side of the Baum-Connes map is functorial in the group $G$. For the right hand side $K(A \rtimes G)$ this is clear for the full crossed product, as he himself points out.

How is this justified?